# How can i develop mobile and desktop applications using html, css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, electron

After research i made on the web, i found two frameworks: for desktop development - [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) and for mobile development - [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)

Are above platforms recommended choices for mobile and desktop development with web technologies? If not which frameworks should we use for this purpose?

Comment: Is desktop app in your case, a standalone application or a website

Comment: I want my application to be standalone desktop application that speaks to the server and exchanges some data with it.

Comment: iOnic will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

There is few technologies regarding to your question. Cordova-PhoneGap-Ionic (they rely on [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)) applications are running on WebViews. This means there may be performance issues if you use them for some goals, for example hard calculations. By the way you can still use native functions via Cordova Plugins too.

Also there are [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) and [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) too. With these technologies, your applications are running on native environment. It looks like these technologies are trending now.

Comment: Thing is though, that even though things run in webviews heavy calculations can still be done on an Server you call through api's.

Don't underestimate JS on webviews though.

Comment: Yeah you are right but native bridges on these frameworks are very important for speed too. For example Trigger.io framework says their native bridge are 5x faster than PhoneGap's. This is huge boost on performance. For further reading i suggest: [link](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-webview/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of different possibilities, for instance OnsenUI, Kendo, Ionic (1 or 2), etc. I would recommend you to spend a bit of time to understand which one is better for your needs, even though I would say that Ionic is pretty popular now.

This page is a good start to have an overview of a few popular ones with a short review. http://www.gajotres.net/best-html5-mobile-app-frameworks-ionic-review/ Please note that Framework7 is not in the list, but might be worth mentionning (but I feel more iOS oriented).

Your question is specific about HTML, CSS and Javascript. But as a side note, please do not forget that you might have other options as well as suggested above (ReactNative, Xamarin with C#...) You may check: http://noeticforce.com/mobile-app-development-cordova-vs-react-native-vs-xamarin